# Xen 4.1+ with local ZFS storage

Tags: xen, zfs

I'm speccing out sandbox VM servers for developers at my company. The requirements for the dom0 hosts are: local, deduplicated ZFS storage (no separate storage servers), and Xen 4.1+ (4.2 is ideal).

I checked out Oracle VM, but it only has Xen 4.0. I also looked at the Xen official [list](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Dom0_Kernels_for_Xen) of supported dom0s, but none of the ZFS-supporting ones (openindiana/illumos and opensolaris) seem to be current enough to run Xen 4.1+.

**Question:**

What operating systems out there have robust (read: stable and decent performance) support for ZFS/dedup, and can smoothly (read: good hardware compatibility) work as dom0 hosts for Xen 4.1+?

If possible, I'd like to avoid compiling Xen and have a stable package, but if that's the way it has to be, I can deal with it. I'd similarly prefer ZFS support to be integrated, rather than run through one of the hack-on kernel extensions/FUSE modules available for non-Oracle Linuxes. Again, if that's not possible, I can deal.

If you care about the why:
The devs need Xen 4.1 or better to do something weird I'm not clear on with CAD and passthrough, and management likes ZFS, so that's a "must have" as well. I know that dedup'd ZFS uses a load of hardware resources, but the powers that be are fine with dumping money into hardware.

Comment: Any resolution?

Comment: Playing around with hacking the FUSE drivers, with a stability test planned in the near future, and messing with Nexenta. I'll give you the check, since you've definitely given me some great pointers. I'll put more info here when I have results. Juggling lots of projects, unfortunately...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like a bad spec. These are disparate technologies... Something like [SmartOS](http://smartos.org/) may be more fitting, except for the [Xen requirement](http://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Questions+from+SmartOS+the+Modern+OS+Webinar#QuestionsfromSmartOStheModernOSWebinar-Q:WhatmadeyoudecidetoportKVMtoSmartOSinsteadofusingtheXencodethathadbeenpreviouslyintegratedintoSolaris?).

If you want ZFS, that's fine. But to do ZFS storage properly and support deduplication without a risk of [performance problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/234475/zfs-destroying-deduplicated-zvol-or-data-set-stalls-the-server-how-to-recover), you will need to engineer for it. That means *lots* of RAM, possibly augmented with an approved [L2ARC SSD cache device](https://serverfault.com/questions/277966/zfs-impact-of-l2arc-cache-device-failure-nexenta). Is this really a use-case for deduplication, or will compression be sufficient? If compression is good enough, then you have more options.

A separate storage device will be the most supportable and scalable solution. That way, you can avoid using immature (at this time) Linux ports and direct the resources into single-purpose hardware. It also gives you flexibility to use the virtualization technology of your choice impacting the entire environment or having to navigate strange dependencies.

I recommend [NexentaStor](http://nexenta.com/corp/) as a ZFS storage solution, but you can certainly roll-your-own with [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/)

What type of hardware will you be using? The ability to [pass raw disks to ZFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations) is going to be crucial, too.

Comment: I'm the first to admit it's a bad spec, but I'm stuck with it. Aren't office politics fun? Good ideas, though. I'll poke around.

Comment: Also, on investigation it doesn't look like KVM as a hypervisor allows passthrough of graphics cards well, which are needed for CAD apparently.

Comment: Well, don't let politics dictate a potentially tough solution. I'd split the technologies. Xen has been left by some vendors for KVM. So finding a supported ZFS solution that also accommodates Xen is going to be tricky... But building Xen hosts and having separate ZFS storage is easily attainable.

Answer (score -1):

ZFS and Linux? It seems to be possible - but far from stable - as this [blog](http://drwetter.eu/blog/zfs_under_linux.en.html) post indicates.

If you really need XEN 4.1 use [SLES11 SP2](http://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/11-SP2/#OtherUpdates). I am in the progress of migration from SLES10 SP4 to there. SP2 has XEN 4.1.2 built in. Further service packs will propably upgrade, too. SLES11 started with 4.0...

[BRTFS](http://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/11-SP2/#fate-306585) might be a good FS for your purposes, too.