# ZFS: will RAM shortage cause trouble?

Tags: solaris, zfs

what can happen if i've not enough RAM with a ZFS with dedup option activated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do it. Dedupe on ZFS is bad news if you haven't planned well for it...

What can happen?

- Your system can slow down considerably in certain operations. Holding the dedplication table in RAM isn't the best use of resources.
- Your system [**can stall for DAYS**](https://serverfault.com/questions/234475/zfs-destroying-deduplicated-zvol-or-data-set-stalls-the-server-how-to-recover) if you delete data or filesystems the wrong way.

If there's any doubt, you shouldn't be using dedupe. Buy more disks. Design for more space. Use COMPRESSION instead... it's a much smarter choice for most data sets. I have yet to find a good application for ZFS deduplication that was worth the planning headache.

Also see:
[Backup storage server with ZFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/403353/backup-storage-server-with-zfs/403392#403392) 
and
 [ZFS - destroying deduplicated zvol or data set stalls the server. How to recover?](https://serverfault.com/questions/234475/zfs-destroying-deduplicated-zvol-or-data-set-stalls-the-server-how-to-recover)

Comment: This confirms what I thought: deduplication is an academic speculation! thanks for the answer

Comment: @CSG De nada!!!